# EOF Exception in DBeaver when establishing a connection

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, dbeaver

I'm using DBeaver and all of a sudden I'm facing this message whenever I try to establish a connection.

[image]

I don't have any additional information about this issue, but if you know where I can find it please let me know and I will provide it.

This occured moments after DBeaver popped a message asking to update de the drivers, so this might be related. So far I have tried to restart the PC and reinstall DBeaver, but with no success so far.

Did this ever happened to you? Any idea on what the problem might be?

Comment: I would say file an issue here [dbeaver issues](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues).

Comment: If you have not done so already, you can check the DBeaver [log files](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Log-files#log-files) for additional information. (Note that the file `.log` is a hidden file (file name starts with a `.`) - in a hidden directory `.metadata`.)

Answer (score 0):

For me also appeared this issue, and the solution was the usage of a Profile.
In SSH tab (right up) there is a Profile drop-down menu. If it was empty, did not work.
If I chose a profile, with the same parameters, it began to work fine.
(It was misleading that the tunnel configuration setting was also good in the non-working situation.)